# regex find a string but not a certain other longer strings containing that same string

Tags: regex

I am looking for some regex to locate a string but not several other longer stings containing the string I am looking for. The search is for foo but the result must not contain foo-core, foo core and foogui and fooi.

Searching for:

```
foo
```

Result must not contain:

```
foo-core
foo core
foogui
fooi
```

Comment: Can you give us an example string on which to perform the RegEx match?

Comment: Yes it is possible  simply use `/\sfoo\s/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The search is for foo but the result must not contain foo-core, foo core and foogui and fooi.

Here is the regex featuring look-ahead that you can use:

```
\bfoo(?![- ]core|(?:gu)?i)\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kM9dR2/2)

The regex matches:

- `\b` - beginning of a word
- `foo` - `foo` but only if it is not followed by....

  - `[- ]` -  `-` or space or `core` or `gui` or `i`
- `\b` - make sure we matched a whole word.

Comment: I've question that here you have given set words that doesn't match those words but if it contains`foo[a-zA-Z]` or something like `foo[0-9]`

Comment: @NarendraSisodia: Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: @NarendraSisodia OP never said it had to match ONLY foo just not foo with those suffixes

Comment: Yes you're right I just asked for the alternate that can be arise too along with it as like `foo more`. Nothing else but I got that

Comment: @NarendraSisodia: If you mean to also disallow matching `foo more`, you can add `| more` to the list of alternatives.

Comment: Then we need to make an array or list of strings that won't be to be matched am I right

Comment: @NarendraSisodia: Yes, a list is a good idea. And to play it safe, I'd have it sorted by the element length in a descending order.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for? Your question should be more specific and provide better examples, I think.

```
foo(?![- ]core|gui|i)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wC4gS6/2)

Comment: What about `foo core`?

Comment: Just add it to the list of options in the negative lookahead capturing group: `foo(?!-core| core|gui|i)`

Comment: @iismathwizard Nice use of character class bracket in the updated answer.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks for bringing that to my attention. I only saw `foo-core` when I read the question originally.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [regular-expressions.com](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). Here is an excerpt that should help you!

*The caret ^ matches the position before the first character in the string. Applying ^a to abc matches a. ^b does not match abc at all, because the b cannot be matched right after the start of the string, matched by ^. See below for the inside view of the regex engine.
Similarly, $ matches right after the last character in the string. c$ matches c in abc, while a$ does not match at all.*

Please add info in the question if you specifically wanted to black list the other string endings or if you are looking to only end the string with foo!